# Is there a way to print a webpage as PDF in landscape mode using Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, pdf

Short question is: can I use Safari to print out a webpage as PDF, but in landscape mode, if no printer is added whatsoever?

---

Details:

First of all, I cannot use Google Chrome to print out the document

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers

and be able to highlight it, because the highlighting is about 1/3 inch off (try highlighting the header or text and we can see).

So I am using Safari.  On my other MacBook Pro, I added a printer, and was able to choose Landscape Mode. But I have a MacBook Air M1 and don't always use that MacBook Pro, and if I use the MacBook Air M1 to print out that webpage, there is no way to choose Landscape Mode, seemingly because no printer is selected, and there is no printer "capability" of printing in landscape mode.

So is there a way to make it work, other than to somehow find a real printer and add a printer?

Comment: In Big Sur (and maybe in other versions of macOS), you can use the File>Export as PDF... option to export a web page **exactly as it is displayed** as a PDF file. You can't select portrait or landscape mode, though.

Comment: @jaume it is quite magical it could make it a PDF WYSIWYG as on the screen. I can make the window narrower or wider, and I get such a PDF. The catch is that, it prints out the black programming code region as all black, and if I highlight it, the highlighting won't show. If I print it, it prints the code as white region which is good to highlight

Answer (score 1):

By default, macOS does provide basic print options of paper size and orientation in the Print menu, even if you don't have a printer. (Though these may need to be 'revealed' using the "Show Details' button.

However, I have always recommended that if you don't have a physical printer, there may be benefits to creating a 'Generic PostScript Printer' print queue.

[image]

The "PDF button" in the print menu does rely on the CUPS print system, and that usually means having some form of print queue.

The other option is to use a dedicated print-to-file queue, like [CUPS-PDF](https://www.cups-pdf.de).

Answer (score 0):

Later on I found the answer on MacBook Air M1 with Big Sur:

When we print the page, the is a "Show Detail" or "Hide Detail" under the page sample. Click on "Show Detail" and it'd show a choice to print in Portrait or Landscape mode.